# Creating different columns with last 2 maxima in each row in a time series data in R

Tags: r

I've a time series data as attached and a table with the local maxima.
Now, what I want is the ouput table with the following fields :

```
date   Close max_1 max_2
```

where `max_1` is the last local maxima before the specified date in the time series and similarly `max_2` is the second last local maxima before that date.

Could anyone please help me do this in R?

output will look like this
   [image: output]

input data

```
dates       Close
5/2/2016    2219.3
5/3/2016    2245.4
5/4/2016    2151.1
5/5/2016    2092.2
5/6/2016    2104.15
5/9/2016    2106
5/10/2016   1987.25
5/11/2016   1967.25
5/12/2016   1870.95
5/13/2016   1862.8
5/16/2016   1795.15
5/17/2016   1722.45
5/18/2016   1661.05
5/19/2016   1582.5
5/20/2016   1739.5
5/23/2016   1729.65
5/24/2016   1685.2
5/25/2016   1714.3
5/26/2016   1709.55
5/27/2016   1710.45
5/30/2016   1683.6
5/31/2016   1692.55
6/1/2016    1708.9
6/2/2016    1700.05
6/3/2016    1685.85
6/6/2016    1666.35
6/7/2016    1654.6
6/8/2016    1644.95
6/9/2016    1644.85
6/10/2016   1644.25
6/13/2016   1744.1
6/14/2016   1704.85
6/15/2016   1703.7
6/16/2016   1688.55
6/17/2016   1831.15
```

maxima's

```
dates   Close
5/3/2016    2245.4
5/9/2016    2106
5/20/2016   1739.5
5/25/2016   1714.3
5/27/2016   1710.45
6/1/2016    1708.9
6/13/2016   1744.1
6/17/2016   1831.15
```

Comment: please provide the data instead of pictures of them.

Comment: @Abdou i have shared the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you get started:

#### data:

Please make sure that the `dates` columns from both `prices` and `maxima` are of `Date` class.

```
#The prices dataset
prices <- structure(list(dates = c("5/2/2016", "5/3/2016", "5/4/2016", 
                                       "5/5/2016", "5/6/2016", "5/9/2016", "5/10/2016", "5/11/2016", 
                                       "5/12/2016", "5/13/2016", "5/16/2016", "5/17/2016", "5/18/2016", 
                                       "5/19/2016", "5/20/2016", "5/23/2016", "5/24/2016", "5/25/2016", 
                                       "5/26/2016", "5/27/2016", "5/30/2016", "5/31/2016", "6/1/2016", 
                                       "6/2/2016", "6/3/2016", "6/6/2016", "6/7/2016", "6/8/2016", "6/9/2016", 
                                       "6/10/2016", "6/13/2016", "6/14/2016", "6/15/2016", "6/16/2016", 
                                       "6/17/2016"), Close = c(2219.3, 2245.4, 2151.1, 2092.2, 2104.15, 
                                                               2106, 1987.25, 1967.25, 1870.95, 1862.8, 1795.15, 1722.45, 1661.05, 
                                                               1582.5, 1739.5, 1729.65, 1685.2, 1714.3, 1709.55, 1710.45, 1683.6, 
                                                               1692.55, 1708.9, 1700.05, 1685.85, 1666.35, 1654.6, 1644.95, 
                                                               1644.85, 1644.25, 1744.1, 1704.85, 1703.7, 1688.55, 1831.15)), .Names = c("dates", 
                                                                                                                                         "Close"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))
#make sure that the dates column is of Date class    
prices$dates <- as.Date(prices$dates,format = "%m/%d/%Y")

#The maxima dataset
maxima <- structure(list(dates = c("5/3/2016", "5/9/2016", "5/20/2016", 
                                       "5/25/2016", "5/27/2016", "6/1/2016", "6/13/2016", "6/17/2016"
    ), Close = c(2245.4, 2106, 1739.5, 1714.3, 1710.45, 1708.9, 1744.1, 
                 1831.15)), .Names = c("dates", "Close"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                              -8L))
#Make sure that the dates column is of Date class
maxima$dates <- as.Date(maxima$dates,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

#### Adding new columns to the prices dataset:

To get this done, you will need to use `lapply` and write a function to grab the rows from the `maxima` dataset that are earlier (less) than a given a date value from the `prices` dataset. Once you get those rows, then you can take the last value (for `max1`) and the second last value (for `max2`). The following is the code:

```
prices$max1 <- lapply(1:nrow(prices), function(x) {
  holder <- maxima[maxima$dates < prices[x,1],2]
  holder <- ifelse(length(holder)>0,holder[length(holder)],NA)
  holder
})

prices$max2 <- lapply(1:nrow(prices), function(x) {
  holder <- maxima[maxima$dates < prices[x,1],2]
  holder <- ifelse(length(holder)>1,holder[length(holder)-1],NA)
  holder
})
```

#### ouput:

```
     dates   Close    max1    max2
 2016-05-02 2219.30      NA      NA
 2016-05-03 2245.40      NA      NA
 2016-05-04 2151.10  2245.4      NA
 2016-05-05 2092.20  2245.4      NA
 2016-05-06 2104.15  2245.4      NA
 2016-05-09 2106.00  2245.4      NA
 2016-05-10 1987.25    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-11 1967.25    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-12 1870.95    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-13 1862.80    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-16 1795.15    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-17 1722.45    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-18 1661.05    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-19 1582.50    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-20 1739.50    2106  2245.4
 2016-05-23 1729.65  1739.5    2106
 2016-05-24 1685.20  1739.5    2106
 2016-05-25 1714.30  1739.5    2106
 2016-05-26 1709.55  1714.3  1739.5
 2016-05-27 1710.45  1714.3  1739.5
 2016-05-30 1683.60 1710.45  1714.3
 2016-05-31 1692.55 1710.45  1714.3
 2016-06-01 1708.90 1710.45  1714.3
 2016-06-02 1700.05  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-03 1685.85  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-06 1666.35  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-07 1654.60  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-08 1644.95  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-09 1644.85  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-10 1644.25  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-13 1744.10  1708.9 1710.45
 2016-06-14 1704.85  1744.1  1708.9
 2016-06-15 1703.70  1744.1  1708.9
 2016-06-16 1688.55  1744.1  1708.9
 2016-06-17 1831.15  1744.1  1708.9
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey..this worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is:

We first create a random sample with 2 tables. table "dates" contain your first dates list and table "table" contains the closing maxima for all weeks?!

```
value <- c(1000,3000,5000,10000,15000)
dates <- as.Date(c("2016-05-21","2016-05-22","2016-05-23","2016-05-        24","2016-05-27"))


table <- data.frame(value,dates)
colnames(table) = c("value","date")

dates <- data.frame(as.Date(c("2016-05-28","2016-05-20","2016-05-27")))
dates$first <- NA
dates$second <- NA
colnames(dates) = c("Date","maxima1","maxima2")
table<- table[rev(order(as.Date(table$date))),]
```

Then we iterate with a for loop and extract the maxima from the previous two dates before the specified date in the table "table".

```
for (i in 1:length(dates$Date)){
        target <- as.Date(dates$Date[i])
        previousdates <- subset(table, date < target)

        dates$maxima1[i] <- previousdates$value[1]
        dates$maxima2[i] <- previousdates$value[2]
}
```

Hope it helps.